# Unable to install Cassandra Driver on mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, cassandra

I am trying to install the cassandra driver on my mac but every time I try:

```
$sudo pip install cassandra-driver
```

it throws an error of

***The directory '/Users/jigarmehta/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent 
   directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been 
   disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If 
   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.***

even though i am using the admin account on my personal mac.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me tackle this please!

Comment: Just an update, I do enter the right password!

Comment: This is resolved. I used Pip3 to install cassandra.